# Multiple select option RTL alignment issue

Tags: html, html-select, right-to-left

I have a multiple select element. When I try to aligned the options to the right, I can't.

I searched the web for many articles but I failed to find the solution.

Comment: can you show the code you left it at or provide a URL?

Comment: In your case, I recommend using the bootstrap-multiselect

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
select { direction: rtl; }
```

Answer (score -1):

All you need is:

```
select { text-align: right; }
```

Comment: There's a difference between rtl and align right. This needs clarifying.

Comment: thank you for your answer but i doesn't work for google chrome browser

Comment: Both text-align and Direction won't work in webkit (Safari, Chrome)